# Powershell script for building CI/CD for Azure Data factory

Tags: powershell, azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I'm planning to build Continous integration and Deployment for Azure Data factory using PowerShell. So all the build and release process which can be done using VSTS has to be done using Powershell. If anyone can share any links or powershell scripts it would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: MS provide a bunch of CmdLets for ADFv2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/?view=azurermps-6.0.0

Comment: Your question might get closed as off-topic pretty soon because you're asking for a resource/approach recommendation instead of a specific narrowed-down problem. Try to be more specific about the problems you're facing with and you're more likely to get help.

Comment: Im looking for build tasks using Powershell script. I have done CI/CD using VSTS, but need to create the Build and release activities (CI/CD) using Powershell script. There isnt enough links available on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean create build/release definition through PowerShell, you can do it through [VSTS REST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/create?view=vsts-rest-5.0) with PowerShell, simple code:

```
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "","{personal access token}")))
$body='{
    "variables": {
        "system.debug": {
            "value": "false",
            "allowOverride": true
        }
    },
    "retentionRules": [
        {
            "branches": [
                "+refs/heads/*"
            ],
            "artifacts": [],
            "artifactTypesToDelete": [
                "FilePath",
                "SymbolStore"
            ],
            "daysToKeep": 10,
            "minimumToKeep": 1,
            "deleteBuildRecord": true,
            "deleteTestResults": true
        }
    ],
    "properties": {},
    "tags": [],
    "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
    "jobTimeoutInMinutes": 60,
    "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 5,
    "process": {
        "phases": [
            {
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "environment": {},
                        "enabled": true,
                        "continueOnError": false,
                        "alwaysRun": false,
                        "displayName": "Azure PowerShell script: FilePath",
                        "timeoutInMinutes": 0,
                        "condition": "succeeded()",
                        "task": {
                            "id": "72a1931b-effb-4d2e-8fd8-f8472a07cb62",
                            "versionSpec": "2.*",
                            "definitionType": "task"
                        },
                        "inputs": {
                            "ConnectedServiceNameSelector": "ConnectedServiceNameARM",
                            "ConnectedServiceName": "",
                            "ConnectedServiceNameARM": "aad18bbf-0333-41bf-99ea-674181d17ada",
                            "ScriptType": "FilePath",
                            "ScriptPath": "$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA/dbtest.ps1",
                            "Inline": "# You can write your azure powershell scripts inline here. \n# You can also pass predefined and custom variables to this script using arguments",
                            "ScriptArguments": "",
                            "TargetAzurePs": "LatestVersion",
                            "CustomTargetAzurePs": ""
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "name": "Phase 1",
                "refName": "Phase_1",
                "condition": "succeeded()",
                "target": {
                    "executionOptions": {
                        "type": 0
                    },
                    "allowScriptsAuthAccessOption": false,
                    "type": 1
                },
                "jobAuthorizationScope": "projectCollection",
                "jobCancelTimeoutInMinutes": 1
            }
        ],
        "type": 1
    },
    "repository": {
        "properties": {
            "cleanOptions": "0",
            "tfvcMapping": "{\"mappings\":[{\"serverPath\":\"$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA\",\"mappingType\":\"map\",\"localPath\":\"\\\\\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA/VS2010UltimTrial.iso\",\"mappingType\":\"cloak\",\"localPath\":\"\"},{\"serverPath\":\"$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA/tools\",\"mappingType\":\"cloak\",\"localPath\":\"\"}]}",
            "labelSources": "0",
            "labelSourcesFormat": "$(build.buildNumber)"
        },
        "id": "$/",
        "type": "TfsVersionControl",
        "name": "Scrum2015",
        "defaultBranch": "$/Scrum2015/ClassLibraryA",
        "rootFolder": "$/Scrum2015",
        "clean": "false",
        "checkoutSubmodules": false
    },
    "processParameters": {},
    "quality": "definition",
    "drafts": [],
    "queue": { 
        "id": 179
    },

    "name": "PowerShellRest2VNext",
    "path": "\\",
    "type": "build",
    "queueStatus": "enabled"
}'
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Body $body
```

Note, you can create a sample build/release definition, then get it through VSTS REST API to get JSON content.

A blog that can help you: [VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases)

If you mean custom build/release task, you can refer to [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts), for powershell, change execution like this:

```
"execution": {
    "PowerShell3": {
      "target": "Hello.ps1",
      "argumentFormat": ""
    }
}
```

Regarding deploy azure data factory, you can refer to: [How to deploy Azure Data Factory pipeline and its dependencies programatically using PowerShell](https://blog.abatishchev.ru/2017/03/28/how-to-deploy-azure-data-factory-pipeline-and-its-dependencies-using-powershell/) (Do not need to call `Login-AzureRMAccount` and `Select-AzureRMSubscrition`, just add Azure PowerShell task to build/release definition).

A 3rd extension: [Azure Data Factory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liprec.vsts-publish-adf)

Comment: Thanks..I'm looking for the first option where i need to do all the build and release tasks in a single powershell script which can be used for CI/CD. So i need to create a json file and call that JSON file in build. If i need to do other tasks like nuget restore, copy files, publish artifacts how can i do these..And also if i need to run these in my private agent what are all the steps i need to follow..

Comment: And which is the best practises to do..either using a vsts task or a single powershell script for CI/CD

Comment: @ArunS Just update the JSON data, you can create a sample build/release definition, then get the detail JSON data through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/build/definitions/get?view=vsts-rest-5.0, after that update the JSON per to the result.

Comment: For VSTS task, you just need to add to build/release definition, but for PowerShell task, you also need to specify another script file (or inline script).

Comment: Thanks Chen for your inputs. Can you suggest which will be the best practise for CI/CD.                                                                                   Option 1 - Build CI & CD using VSTS Tasks.                                                   Option 2 - Build CI & CD using Powershell.

Comment: For option 2 I'm still not clear on the process. So as per your note  "Note, you can create a sample build/release definition, then get it through VSTS REST API to get JSON content."  I need to follow the below steps -                                                                                        
1) For ADF take a Build using VSTS tasks.                                         2) Get the JSON content using VSTS REST API                                      3) Call the JSON content in the Powershell script. Hope my understanding is correct.

Comment: @ArunS Both of these way are ok, using VSTS task is better, because the custom task can be used in other build/release directly without additional script. but using PowerShell task is simple.

Comment: Yes, your are right, just create a sample build/release definition, then get the JSON content of it through REST API, which can be used to create the build definition (can remove unnecessary properties, refer to the sample content in my answer)

Comment: my code is available in github and dont have vsts as part of my project..and if i want to build continous integration and deployment what will be the approach to follow..

Comment: @ArunS For additional issue, I recommend that you can open a new thread.

Comment: Created a seperate thread for this..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732330/continous-integration-and-continous-deployment-for-azure-services-in-github..see if you can check and respond on this..