# Continuous integration and Continuous deployment for Azure services in Github

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I need to do CI/CD for my Azure services like Azure Data Factory; Azure SQL DB;Azure SQL DWH; Azure Data Lake Analytics and my source code control is Github and don't have VSTS services in my project. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a free VSTS account (limited resources) which allows you to build a CI/CD pipeline, run load tests, etc. Find more details at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/create-account-msa-or-work-student?view=vsts
- https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/pricing/

The following page contains good content (e.g. tutorials, articles, videos, etc.) on CI/CD with VSTS (including Azure):

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/index?view=vsts

Comment: Thanks Evandro..I will not be able to use VSTS in my project..i have github as source control and if I want to build CI/CD for my azure services (ADF,ADLA, SQL DB & DWH) how do i need to approach..

Comment: VSTS can pull the source from public GitHub. Are you using GitHub Enterprise without external access? You can use  PowerShell + ARM templates to deploy the Azure components. It's possible to use Terra form as well and there is an extension on VSTS marketplace, but keep in mind Azure SQL Geo-replication deployment is not supported as of now.

Comment: I'm planning to build CI/CD tool for projects in my team using Github..so for this i need to build a ARM template and call the ARM template using powershell script.Any links or samples should help get started in this..And how I will enable CI/CD in this approach..